# JavaScript - Draw circle on canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I am practicing JavaScript and HTML so please stay with me.

My below code should create popup a message and a canvas (rectangle) when the page loads. When I click on the canvas, it will draw a red circle and circle changes to red when double click on canvas (rectangle).

For some reasons, it does not draw red circle when click on the canvas. Would you please help me to fix this issue and tell me on how to implement the change color function?

Thank you for any inputs.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style type="text/css">
  canvas {border: 1px solid #000;}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
   // popup message when page loads
   function popUpMessage() {
     alert("Please click left top corner");
   }

   var canvas = document.getElementById("imgCanvas");
   var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

   // click canvas
   function clickCanvas(imageId) {
      canvas.style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("images").style.overflowY = "hidden";
      var img = new Image(400, 300);
      img.src = document.getElementById(imageId).src;
      context.drawImage(img, (0), (0)); //onload....
    }

    // draw red circle on click
    function drawCircle(e) {
      posx = 100;
      posy = 100;
      context.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(posx, posy, 100, 0, 2*Math.PI);
      context.fill();
    }

    // change from red to blue on double click
    function changeColor() {
    }

    window.drawCircle = drawCircle;

  </script>



  <body onload="popUpMessage()">
    <div id="images"></div>
    <canvas style="margin:0;padding:0;position:relative;left:50px;top:50px;" id="imgCanvas" width="400" height="300" onclick="drawCircle(event)"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

Updated Code with single and double click function.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            canvas {border: 1px solid #000;}
        </style>
    </head>

    <body onload="popUpMessage()">
        <div id="images"></div>
        <canvas style="margin:0;padding:0;position:relative;" id="imgCanvas" width="400" height="300" onclick="drawCircle(event)" ondblclick="changeColor(event)"></canvas>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // popup message when page loads
            function popUpMessage() {
                alert("Please click left top corner");
            }

            var canvas = document.getElementById("imgCanvas");
            var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var timer;
    var status = 1;

            // click canvas
            function clickCanvas(imageId) {
                canvas.style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById("images").style.overflowY = "hidden";
                var img = new Image(400, 300);
                img.src = document.getElementById(imageId).src;
                context.drawImage(img, (0), (0)); //onload....
            }

            // draw red circle on click
            function drawCircle(e) {

                 status = 1;
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            if (status == 1) {
                posx = 100;
                posy = 100;
                context.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
                context.beginPath();
                context.arc(posx, posy, 100, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
                context.fill();
            }
        }, 5);


            }

// change from red to blue on double click
function changeColor(event) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        status = 0;
popUpMessage();
    }

            window.drawCircle = drawCircle;
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please use the developer tool that comes with your browser, or install and run Firebug to see any run-time JavaScript errors.

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle so we can see what the code does right now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rzjrrer6/2/) when the JavaScript is included in `<body>`

- Your code do not have `<head>` tag. Place your `CSS` inside `<head>` tag.
- Move you JavaScript to end of the `<body>` tag.

Here is your code which works perfectly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            canvas {border: 1px solid #000;}
        </style>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylespacewars.css" />
        <script src="jsspacewars.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.js"></script>
        <title></title>
    </head>

    <body onload="popUpMessage()">
        <div id="images"></div>
        <canvas style="margin:0;padding:0;position:relative;left:50px;top:50px;" id="imgCanvas" width="400" height="300" onclick="drawCircle(event)" ondblclick="changeColor(event)"></canvas>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // popup message when page loads
            function popUpMessage() {
                alert("Please click left top corner");
            }

            var canvas = document.getElementById("imgCanvas");
            var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

            // click canvas
            function clickCanvas(imageId) {
                canvas.style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById("images").style.overflowY = "hidden";
                var img = new Image(400, 300);
                img.src = document.getElementById(imageId).src;
                context.drawImage(img, (0), (0)); //onload....
            }

            // draw red circle on click
            function drawCircle(e) {
                posx = 100;
                posy = 100;
                context.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
                context.beginPath();
                context.arc(posx, posy, 100, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
                context.fill();
            }

            // change from red to blue on double click
            function changeColor() {
                posx = 100;
                posy = 100;
                context.fillStyle = "#0000FF";
                context.beginPath();
                context.arc(posx, posy, 100, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
                context.fill();
            }

            window.drawCircle = drawCircle;
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out... such a silly mistake. :( Would you please give me some ideas on how to do the change color function too?

Comment: Define "color function"

Comment: @LiamDo  Do you want a red circle on `click` or `double click`? If on `double click`, then do you want anything to happen just on `click`?

Comment: @Shrinivas Shukla: one click is draw red circle, double click will change the red circle to blue. I am able to implement the single and double click (please see my updated code). Now I need to change the popup function to change color function.

Comment: As per my knowledge, you can't change the color of the shapes and contents already present on a canvas. (Seems logical too). See updated answer.

Comment: Then, can we draw the new canvas with different color?

Comment: No need to draw new canvas. Just change the `fillStyle` to `blue` by `context.fillStyle = "#0000FF";` and draw the same `arc` again. This new blue circle will overlap the old red circle.

Comment: Yes, that's it! I am able to draw my red and blue circle with single and double click now. Thank you very much for your help!